# Subscribe, publish dynamic collection made in run time

Tags: meteor, angular-meteor

I am trying to make a chat application in meteorJS and i was thinking of making a seperate collection for each groups dynamically when they initiate chat, I want to publish and subscribe that collection for transmitting chat information and all the group user can subscribe it, but i am not being able to create a collection dynamically.

I tried making a function which gets call when the user subscribe the collection.

```
this.createDb =(name) ->
  @ChatDb = new Mongo.Collection(name)
  return true
```

everything is fine, but when i subscribe this collection from client side, ChatDb is unknown, Can any one help me with this, that would be great. :)

ps- i am writing code in angular-meteor framework

Answer (score 0):

[Andrew Mao](https://github.com/mizzao)'s answer to a [similiar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24394680/2041954):

> In most instances, you probably don't want to create multiple
>   collections, but instead use one collection and send views of it to
>   clients depending on their subscription.
>
> You may want to check out the
>   https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-partitioner package I've built which
>   is designed especially for this purpose, and includes an example for
>   how to do this for multiple chat rooms. You can also see
>   https://github.com/mizzao/CrowdMapper for an implemented example.

I haven't done Meteor for a while now so I couldn't give you a solid answer. But I remember quite clearly that creating collections dynamically is not the recommended way for achieving what you want to do.