# Is it possible to generate dynamically-named MongoDB Collections?

Tags: jquery, mongodb, meteor

Normally, MongoDB Collections are defined like this:

```
DuckbilledPlatypi = new Mongo.Collection("duckbilledplatypi");
```

I want to, though, dynamically generate Collections based on user input. For example, I might want it to be:

```
RupertPupkin20151212_20151218 = new Mongo.Collection("rupertPupkin20151212_20151218");
```

It would be easy enough to build up the Collection name:

```
var dynCollName = username + begindate +'_'+ enddate;
```

...and then pass "dynCollName") to Mongo.Collection:

```
 = new Mongo.Collection(dynCollName);
```

...but what about the Collection instance name - how can that be dynamically generated? I would need something like:

```
"RupertPupkin20151212_20151218".ToRawName() = new Mongo.Collection(dynCollName);
```

-or:

```
"RupertPupkin20151212_20151218".Unstringify() = new Mongo.Collection(dynCollName);
```

...but AFAIK, there's no such thing...

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times. No - don't do this. I recently added a section to [common mistakes](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) to make this point clear.

Comment: Thanks for that; I'll go over that page of yours with a fine-toothed comb.

Comment: Really bad idea. Why do you want to do this? Whats the underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meteor, define collections dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394680/meteor-define-collections-dynamically)

Comment: I hadn't definitely decided to do that, just wondering if it's possible while I ponder the possibility. In any case, I will have to have master/detail Collections, but my "fear" is that, if I keep all the data in one static Collection, the Collection will get huMONGOus (maybe that's not a problem) and performance would suffer.

Comment: Look into adding Indexes to your Collections if performance is an issue.  http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a single client instance, yes, and you could [dynamically reference it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690350/how-would-you-find-a-collection-dynamically-in-meteor-with-a-value). However in the general case (using it to sync data between the server and all connected clients), no.

I address this point in the *Dynamically created collections* section of [common mistakes](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) in a little detail, but the fundamental problem is that it would be **highly** complex to get all connected clients to agree on a dynamically generated set of collections.

It's much more likely that a finite set of collections where some have a flexible schema, is actually what you want. As Andrew Mao points out in the answer to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24394680/meteor-define-collections-dynamically), [partitioner](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-partitioner) is another tool available to help address some cases which give rise to this question.

Comment: My app will always be single client.